# tailwind styles dont apply in vue js project

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

i'm new to vue js an wanted to write a fancy little demo.
I was trying to use tailwindcss in a new project.

I've created the project with

```
vue create vue-tailwind-template
```

and added tailwind with

```
vue add tailwind
```

I removed the demo component "helloworld" an all styles. In App.vue i try to use an div with class "bg-red", but no red background in output. These are my project files. Does anybody see the problem? Thank you in advance.

Sven

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {}
  }
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <div class="bg-red"><p>Hallo</p></div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './assets/tailwind.css'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

Comment: Have a look at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
Classname "bg-red" doesn't exist. I had to use a number to define color intensity, e.g. "bg-red-500"